# Can a Parent React Component's function have a new React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I came across a application that uses render method Like below

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
        render: function () {

          var Child1 = React.createClass({
              render: function () {
                  return <SomeView/>   //Child1 View 
              }
            })  

          var Child2 = React.createClass({
              render: function () {
                  return <SomeOtherView/> //Child2 View
              }
            })

          return(    // Parent View with Child1 and Child2
              <View>
                  <Child1/>
                  <Child2/>
              </View>

          )
        }
})
```

Are they any performance issues involved in this, until this point I was thinking a render should be as light as possible and

1 . All the logic goes into the ComponentWillMount and ComponentDidMount

2 . All the React Views are generated seperatly(Outside of Parent ReactClass) and added to Parent on Render.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, no logic should be happening in the render and it should be as pure as possible. What this is doing is creating `Child1` and `Child2` on every single render which will affect performance. Normally you would have those in separate files and import them into the Parent for use.